# reading text input in jsp

Tags: jsp, httprequest, textinput

I would like to know what is the best way to read a text input on a jsp page?
Could anyone tell what is the difference between the two java code separated by VS?

```
  <input type=text id=myInput value="myInput">
  <%
        String data = request.getParameter("myinput");
   //VS
        request.setAttribute("myInput", data);  

  %>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but ... the first one reads a parameter and the second one sets an attribute?

Comment: The second doesn't do the job you want, so that can impossibly be one of the "best" ways. Even more, there's no means of a "best" way at all. There's only one way to obtain a request parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the difference between a request `attribute` and `parameter`.

A request `parameter` is always a `String` (i.e. they are always represented by a `String` even integers, booleans, floats etc like for eg: "1", "1.1", "true") and in a certain URL like: `http://google.com/search?q=question&cat=images` `q` and `cat` are called `parameters` or `query parameters` and their value is `question` and `images` respectively. This is an example of `GET` request.
`POST` request parameters would be those which are submitted through an html `<form>`.

Now request `attributes` are objects as opposed to `parameters`. And their value can only be set by using `request.setAttribute("myInput", data);` here `data` can be a `String`, instance  or object of a `Person` class etc, in short `data` is an object.

And one more difference is you don't have a method `request.setParameter("myinput", data);` there is no such method, so request parameters are only set when a html `<form>` is submitted or the URL contains parameters as explained above.

Now with `parameters` you can get them as:

```
String data = request.getParameter("myinput");`
```

even if value of `"myInput"` may be an `int` or `boolean`.

For an attribute you can get them as:

```java
String data = (String) request.getAttribute("myInput");` // if "myInput" is a String
Person data = (Person) request.getAttribute("myInput");`  // if "myInput" is an instance of Person class
Long data = (Long) request.getAttribute("myInput");`  // if "myInput" is a Long
```

So now you know what is the different between the two codes, one reads  the value from a request parameter (`request.getParameter()`) and other from request attribute (`request.getAttribute()`).

Let me know if this is not what you wanted.

Comment: When I tried to prinln the value of data, it returned null, I wonder what is the cause of that?

Comment: Well, one thing is this ` <input type=text id=myInput value="myInput">` does not have a `name="myInput"` attribute to get the `data` from `getParameter()` method. Other thing is you have to submit the `<form>` in which you have written `<input >` to get the `data`.

Comment: I will recommend you to go through basic JSP tutorials.

Comment: I would say our [tag:jsp] [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) is also a good place to know these things.